# in Laravel route , why using default and why to struct route like this

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, routes, backend

```
Route::get('/atomic/{id}',[ApiController::class,'index'])->defaults('task', 'atomic');
```

why use defaults here and what is a task & atomic, and Api controller does not have an index function. Please explain this route properly.

I am new to laravel I tried to google for a solution but no result

Answer (score 2):

`defaults` method helps to pass extra params to `controller` without passing as `route params`

> As a backend engineer you’ll often be asked to produce URL patterns
> that just don’t work with the rest of the site without breaking your
> current routing structure. Often you’ll create what’s known as a slug
> for your content, a simple hyphen separated string which is unique in
> the system. A typical slug would be just generated from the title like
> “My Simple Article” becomes as a slug my-simple-article. This way
> there’s a unique string in the system for each post.
>
> If you’ve already been implementing routes like this in your system
> you’ll likely have urls that look like /post/{slug} but you know now
> that’s not going to be good enough. Your company’s marketing team or
> SEO wizards want it to be /{slug} and that’s pretty tricky. You can’t
> create the pattern /{post-slug} because it’s going to confuse the
> system. What is you have an About Us page or a Contact Us page which
> equally important urls like /about-us and /contact-us respectively.
> The problem here being that the routing system might pick up the
> /about-us link and believe it’s meant to be a slug for a Post model.
> At this point Laravel will simply not find the model and throw a HTTP
> 404 error instead. Not good.
>
> This is where the ‘defaults’ method on routes comes into use to save
> the day.

if I consider your example then

```
Route::get('/atomic/{id}',[ApiController::class,'index'])->defaults('task', 'atomic');
```

while hitting URL `http://127.0.0.1:8002/atomic/1` then in the controller,you will get both params `$id` and `$task`

```
 public function index($id,$task){

   dump($task);
   dump($id);
}
```

the output of the above will be `atomic` and `1`

defaults() method nothing but key-value pair params

```
 /**
     * Set a default value for the route.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function defaults($key, $value)
    {
        $this->defaults[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }
```

suppose if you want to pass multiple array params then use  `setDefaults` method like below

```
 Route::get('/atomic/{id}',[ApiController::class,'index'])->setDefaults([
    'tasks'=> 'atomics',
    'postTitle'=>'post title goes here'
]);
```

then in controller

```
public function index($id,$tasks,$postTitle){
        dump($tasks);
        dump($postTitle);
        dump($id);
 }
```

now if you hit URL `http://127.0.0.1:8002/atomic/1` then it will print

```
atomics
post title goes here
1
```

Ref : [The Power of Laravel’s Route ‘defaults’ for making root level SEO pages](https://medium.com/@SlyFireFox/the-power-of-laravels-route-defaults-for-making-root-level-seo-pages-ae6da1d9fd51)